# How to get UTC formatted date in moment?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am trying to get UTC formatted date from some date , which comes from server. I am getting from the server a string

> 2018-11-22 00:02:27

I have to convert it to UTC and do it this way `

```
moment('2018-11-22 00:02:27').utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

but i got this `

```
"2018-11-21 20:00:00"
```

What have i done wrong ?

Comment: try removing  the quotes `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'` leave it empty like this `format()`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```js
var yourDate = '2018-11-22 00:02:27';
var utcDate = new Date(yourDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' 00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are overwriting the uct format passing params in the format()

```
moment('2018-11-22 00:02:27').utc().format()
```